# JOptionPane , Como dar fomato negrita solo a una parte del texto del componente

Tags: java

Como poner un mensaje en negrita tengo esto de ejemplo

Por decir tengo esto código:

```
public void pedirFecha(){
JDateChooser jd = new JDateChooser(); 
String message = "porfavor ingrese una fecha ";
Object[] params = {message, jd};
params[0] =   message.concat("\n FECHA NO DISPONIBLE: La fecha  ingresada 
ya fue asignada para  esta operacion");  // esto debe ir en negrita
int nbot=0;
 nbot= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, params, "INDEXACION ", 
JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es crear un `JLabel` y asignarle el formato que necesites.

```
    JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel("elMensaje");
    etiqueta.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, etiqueta, "elTitulo", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

Así quedaría

[image]

Saludos.

Comment: gracias amigo por tu ayuda